# How to get IPv4, gateway and netmask address in shell?

Tags: bash, networking, sh

How to detect IPv4, gateway and netmask and DNS address in shell?

I need this to modify a [script](https://github.com/fubralimited/CentOS-KVM-Image-Tools/) to automate deployment of virtual machines.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote? Is not this a legitimate question for this site?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way, but very unreliable, if you know what interface you need could be:

```
ifconfig_line=$(ifconfig wlan0 | grep -sw "inet" | tr ":" " ")
echo "IP: "$(echo $ifconfig_line | awk {'print $3'})
echo "Mask:"$(echo $ifconfig_line | awk {'print $7'})
echo "Gateway: "$(route -n |head -n3|tail -n1|awk '{print $2}')
echo "DNS: "$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: ifconfig: interface wlan0 does not exist

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, this answer was written 6 years ago. Chances are the name of the wireless interface has changed to something different than `wlan0` (that's why I said it was _very unreliable_). I'd invite you type just `ifconfig` and see which is the name for the wireless interface now. Or take a look at this other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/286721/16046